# does it make sense to cache in private field arrays that not part of the class?

Tags: oop

One method of my class need fresh copy of some array for internal stuff, so I should write something like that:

```
public void FrequentlyCalledMethod {
    int[] a = new int[100];
    ....
```

But because method is frequently called and because content of the array doesn't make sense (it will be replaced anyway) and because array is big enough i want to optimize and write something like that:

```
private int[] a = new int[100];
public void FrequentlyCalledMethod {
    ....
```

Assuming that method is called 100 times per second I will save about 100 * 100 * sizeof(int) bytes of heap memory every second.

The problem is that now class declaration is "dirty". It contains in field the information that only one method needs. Having too much such fields will make class very "unreadable" as "normal" fields will be mixed with "perfomance optimizations" field.

What can I do? Or I should just choose either perfomance or readablity? Can I have both somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**No** your class declaration is not dirty. **Class declaration is dirty only when you mangle its public interface.** And this is a private field. Private fields are used for this.

If you are too worried about the too many private variables then try using small classes. If a method needs 3 private variables you can create a class with those 3 variables and store the object as private filed in current class.

```
class A{
    private int a;
    private int b;
    private int c;
    public int get_num(){
        return a+b+c;
    }
}
```

you can use this,

```
class B{
    private int a;
    private int b;
    private int c;
    public int get_num(){
        return a+b+c;
    }
}

class A{
    private B b;
    public int get_num(){
        return b.get_num();
    }
}
```

Comment: what if all methods will store theirs stuff in private fields? how managable such class would be?

Comment: @javapowered it all depends. Eventually you write whatever needed. The final solution matters, no?

Comment: Managing such class is class writers responsibility. Too many private fields are not rare rather its common. The rule is dont mangle the public interface.

Answer (score 0):

If the first case, the array inside `FrequentlyCalledMethod`  is referenced using a local variable, so it will be garbage-collected when the method ends: there's no heap over-usage in that scenario.

However, if you declare your array as a member attribute; the array instance will persist for all your parent-object life, even if the method `FrequentlyCalledMethod`  is called or not.

In conclusion, if you wanna preserve heap-space and make your program more memory efficient go with **local attributes** and avoid instance variables in your particular case.

Comment: `even if the method FrequentlyCalledMethod is called or not.` - name of the method prompts us how ofthen this method is called

Comment: As I said, even if the method is not called; every instance attribute is in heap during object life.